# Rebooting using bolt

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use bolt to reboot a server using command, this used to work but I'm now getting hit with an error:

```
bolt --format json command run 'sudo /sbin/reboot' --targets <a_valid_server> -u reboot_user --private-key /home/reboot_user/.ssh/id_rsa
terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true)
<snip...>
/opt/puppetlabs/bolt/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:75:in `select': closed stream (IOError)
```

The command works and the server reboots, but I don't need the error relating to the stream being cut short (this is expected behaviour).

I've looked at using `plan run reboot` as an alternative, but it seems to require a password (which isn't necessary).

Comment: You could change the ad-hoc command to a script that rescues the `Exception`.

Comment: You could use a command that schedules a reboot instead of rebooting directly.  For example, `/sbin/shutdown -r +1` schedules a reboot for one minute in the future.  That should afford enough time for `bolt` to terminate cleanly.  And `reboot` uses `shutdown` to do its work anyway, at least in any execution context accessible remotely to Bolt, so that gives you exactly the same reboot behavior once it actually commences.

Comment: I've not got that syntax with my copy of shutdown, it's a nice idea.